# How to store last value from a pyomo optimization loop and use it as initialisation for the next optimization loop?

Tags: loops, variables, pyomo

**UPDATE**

Busy with an optimization on battery storage, I face an issue while trying to optimize the model based on loops of 36 hours, for example, running for a full year of data.
By doing this, I reinitialize the variable that matters at each step and therefore compromising the model. How to extract the last value of a variable and use it for the next iteration as first value ? Here is the problem in a simple way:

```
#creation of list to store last variable values:
df1=[]
df2=[]
df3=[]

# Loop  
for i in range (0,3)
        step = 36
        first_model_hour = step * i
        last_model_hour = (step * (i+1)) - 1
        
        model = ConcreteModel() 

        model.T = Set(doc='hour of year',initialize=df.index.tolist())
        model.A = Var(model.T, NonNegativeReals)
        model.B = Var(model.T, NonNegativeReals)
        model.C = Var(model.T, NonNegativeReals)

     def constraints_x(model,t)
           for t == 0
               return model.C == 100
           elif t == first_model_hour
               return model.C[t] == model.A[from previous loop] + model.B[from previous loop] + model.C[from previous loop]           
           else
               return model.C[t] == model.A[t-1]+model.B[t-1]+model.C[t-1]
       
       model.constraint = Constraint(model.T, rule=constraint_x)
        
       solver = SolverFactory('cbc')
       solver.solve(model)
       
       df1.append(model.S[last_model_hour])
       df2.append(model.B[last_model_hour])
       df3.append(model.C[last_model_hour])
```

Is it possible to retrieve the last value of variables from pyomo to use it a initialization for the next loop and hence not loosing the continuous state of charge of the battery over time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full model that implements what I think you want to do; which is to carry over a value from a previous iteration.  This builds on the previous answer/example.

```
# rolling time horizon

import pyomo.environ as pyo

periods = 3
num_segments = 4

starting_value = 2.0

solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')

for period in range(periods):
    segments = list(range(period*num_segments, (period + 1) * num_segments))  # the time segments in this per

    model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
    model.S = pyo.Set(initialize=segments)
    model.X = pyo.Var(model.S, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

    # assign the first value and fix it
    model.X[model.S.first()] = starting_value
    model.X[model.S.first()].fix()

    # dummy constraint to constrain each value to 1 greater than previous.
    def C1(model, s):
        if s == model.S.first():
            return pyo.Constraint.Skip
        return model.X[s] <= model.X[s-1] + 1

    model.C1 = pyo.Constraint(model.S, rule=C1)

    # obj:  maximize X
    model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=pyo.summation(model.X), sense=pyo.maximize)

    # solve
    result = solver.solve(model)
    assert(result.Solver()['Termination condition'].value == 'optimal')  # a little insurance
    # print(result)
    # model.display()

    starting_value = pyo.value(model.X[model.S.last()]) + 1

    # rolling printout of results...
    print(f'From iteration {period}:')
    model.X.display()
```

#### Yields:

```
From iteration 0:
X : Size=4, Index=S
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      0 :     0 :   2.0 :  None :  True :  True : NonNegativeReals
      1 :     0 :   3.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
      2 :     0 :   4.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
      3 :     0 :   5.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
From iteration 1:
X : Size=4, Index=S
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      4 :     0 :   6.0 :  None :  True :  True : NonNegativeReals
      5 :     0 :   7.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
      6 :     0 :   8.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
      7 :     0 :   9.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
From iteration 2:
X : Size=4, Index=S
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      8 :     0 :  10.0 :  None :  True :  True : NonNegativeReals
      9 :     0 :  11.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
     10 :     0 :  12.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
     11 :     0 :  13.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
```

Comment: Thanks AirSquid I am progressing and it works so far. Is it possible to fix as a model.X a calucation of different variables ? Phyically it would be computing the state of charge +/- energy discharged or charged from the grid. As such the state of charge remains the same from one loop  to the other but my attempts to include a calculation to include in model.X the energy througput at the .last() moment are not succesfull. Is it doable in first instance ? I

Answer (score 0):

This is a very long post where I think you could have whittled it down to a more minimal example.  I think you are asking if/how you can set the value of a particular variable (in your case the first indexed one) from some known value (in your case, something from the preceding run).

You can do this by simply assigning a value to the variable, and then "fixing" the value for that run, then go on to solve...

```
In [11]: import pyomo.environ as pyo

In [12]: model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

In [13]: model.S = pyo.Set(initialize=range(3))

In [14]: model.X = pyo.Var(model.S, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

In [15]: model.X[0]=3.2

In [16]: model.X[0].fix()

In [17]: model.X.pprint()
X : Size=3, Index=S
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      0 :     0 :   3.2 :  None :  True : False : NonNegativeReals
      1 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
      2 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
```

Some perspective on your model...  solving an optimization model over ~9000 time steps is a little over the top, even if you attack it by chopping it up as you did.  You might try a few other things such as increasing your time interval to maybe 4-6 hours, or, maybe more real-world to assume that over certain periods of interest, the system will start/stop in roughly the same state (same battery state) so just solve for a week in a particular season or time period where you think the system will perform differently and say the battery starts/stops at 80%...  Just a couple ideas...

Comment: Sure 9000 is not easy for pyomo sometimes. I succeeded but not always depending on dataset available
For the fixing, i cannot as it concerns the state of charge. So i run an optimization loop for 36 hours, store the state of charge of the  last hour (36) and use it in the next loop as state of charge for the beginning of this next loop (37)so the system knows where it must start. So the number cannot be fixed in principle. Another question is if it is doable like that or not. This is why I created list to store those parameters but still face index length issues...

Comment: an index with 9000 elements is not a problem at all.  Perhaps I didn't understand the focus of your question.  You can also use the `.first()` and `.last()` to get specific first/last items out of your index and fix them if needed.

Comment: starting_value = value(model.S[model.T.last()]) + value(model.Ein[model.T.last()]) - value(model.Eout[model.T.last()])
I tried this as a calculation to store the state of charge but I got a not feasible as returned error. Any idea how to overcome htis ?